# How can I make honey drip down a surface endlessly?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I am trying to recreate a concert visual of Ariana Grande's. The visual looks like a white liquid dripping down a wall. This goes on for 4422 frames. I tried with particles and and icosphere but it did not give me the dripping effect. What I am trying to make is a liquid dripping slowly down a surface that goes on for a long time. I will insert a photo. Someone please help[image: Ariana Grande Visual]![this is the effect I want. It drips down for 3 minutes]

Answer (score 2):

Animated UV map:

One way of going about this is to set up an animated UV map. You will have to have a good material for your honey, and then you animate your UV texture mapping so that the texture appears to be dripping down the sphere.

Here I have started with a UV sphere and kept the default unwrap:
[image]

I've set up a simple material using only a texture for the base color. The effect will look much better if you also have normal and roughness textures. If you have the node-wrangler addon enabled (included in Blender, just turn it on in prefs), select your image texture and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to add the Texture Coordinate and Mapping nodes. Plug these into every image texture you end up using.

[image]

In terms of the actual animation, you're going to be animating the Y-coordinate of the Mapping node. I inserted a single keyframe at frame 0 with Y=0.0, and a single keyframe at frame 60 (or whatever the last frame of your animation is) with Y=1.0.

The reason you set the first keyframe at frame 0 even though your animation starts playing at frame 1 is so that you don't have two frames with the same position.

Make sure you set the interpolation mode for these keyframes to linear.

Here is a basic demo of the set up:
[image]